# React Navbar is not aligning horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

I am using React to build a Navbar with a Brand logo, Home, Profile, and contact button icons which when hovered upon would animate to their respective texts, 'Home', 'Profile', and 'Contact' respectively.

Currently, my icons are stacked up vertically and are beyond the boundaries of the NavBar and div elements. I have even tried react-bootstrap but am unable to get the desired output.

[image: Current Output]

[image: Desired Output]

Here's what I did:

```
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.scss'
import LogoS from '../../../assets/images/taha-logo1.png'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faEnvelope, faHome, faUser } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const NavBar = () => (
    <div className='nav-bar'>
        <Link className='logo' to='/'>
            <img src={LogoS} alt="logo" />
        </Link>
        <nav>
            <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" to="/">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} color="#4d4d4e" />
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" className="about-link" to="/about">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} color="#4d4d4e" />
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" to="/contact">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} color="#4d4d4e" />
            </NavLink>
        </nav>
    </div>
)

export default NavBar
```

The scss Code is:

```
.nav-bar{
background: #181818;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: 3;
min-width: 500px;

.logo{
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 0;
    justify-content: left;

    img{
        display: block;
        margin: 8px;
        margin-left: 2%;
        width: 24px;
        height: 80%;
        }
    }
}

nav {
display: block;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -120px;
width: 210px;

a{
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #4d4d4e;  
  display: block;
  line-height: 51px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;

  i{
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  &:hover{
    color: #ffd700;

    svg{
        opacity: 0;
    }

    &:after{
        opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  &:after{
    content: '';
    font-size: 9px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  &:first-child{
    &::after{
        content: 'HOME';

            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using flexbox for your 'nav' and '.nav-bar' ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using it, but it won't stack it horizontally.